# AWS Amplify filter for @searchable annotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Currently I am using a DynamoDB instance for my social media application. While designing the schema I sticked to the "one table" rule. So I am putting every data in the same table like posts, users, comments etc. 
Now I want to make flexible queries for my data. [Here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#searchable) I found out that I could use the **`@searchable`** annotation to create an Elastic Search instance for a table which is annotated with **`@model`**

In my GraphQL schema I only have one `@model`, since I only have one table. My problem now is that I don't want to make everything in the table searchable, since that would be most likely very expensive. There are some data which don't have to be added to the *Elastic Search* instance (For example comment related data). 
How could I handle it ? Do I really have to split my schema down into multiple tables to be able to manage the **`@searchable`** annotation ? Couldn't I decide If the row should be stored to the Elastic Search with help of the Partitionkey / Primarykey, acting like a filter ?

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation of the `amplify-cli` uses a predefined `python` **Lambda** that are added once we add the **@searchable** directive to one of our models.

The **Lambda** code can not be edited and currently, there is no option to define a custom **Lambda**, you read about it
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1113
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1022

If you want a custom **Lambda** where you can filter what goes to the Elasticsearch Instance, you can follow the steps described here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1113#issuecomment-476193632

The closest you can get is by creating a template in `amplify\backend\api\myapiname\stacks\` where you can manage all the resources related to **Elasticsearch**. A good start point is to

1. Add **@searchable** to one of your model in the **schema.grapql**
2. Run `amplify api gql-compile`
3. Copy the generated template in the *build* folder, `\amplify\backend\api\myapiname\build\stacks\SearchableStack.json` to  `amplify\backend\api\myapiname\stacks\`
4. Remove the **@searchable** directive from the model added in step 1
5. Start editing your new template copied in step 3
6. Add a **Lambda** and use it in the template as the resolver for the **DynamoDB Stream**

Using this approach will give you total control of the resources related to the **Elasticsearch service**, but, will also require to do it all by your own.

Or, just go by creating a table for each model.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to override the generated streaming function code as well.

thanks to the AWS Support for the information provided

leaved a message on the related github issue as well https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/437#issuecomment-1351556948

All you need is to run

- amplify override api
- edit the corresponding overrode.ts

change the code with the `resources.opensearch.OpenSearchStreamingLambdaFunction.code`

```
resources.opensearch.OpenSearchStreamingLambdaFunction.functionName = 'python_streaming_function';
resources.opensearch.OpenSearchStreamingLambdaFunction.handler = 'index.lambda_handler';
resources.opensearch.OpenSearchStreamingLambdaFunction.code = {
    zipFile: `
# python streaming function customized code goes here
`
}
```

Resources:
[1] https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/override/#customize-amplify-generated-resources-for-searchable-opensearch-directive
[2]AWS::Lambda::Function Code - Properties - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#aws-properties-lambda-function-code-properties